# SSE to Neon (_mm_movelh_ps)

Tags: c, sse, neon

Im moving some SSE code to Neon and Im cannot find any equivalent to _mm_movelh_ps. I google quite a bit cannot find anything... Am I missing something? Is THERE any Neon function that does the same thing or I will have to implement it on CPU (not ideal).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSE has 128-bit vector registers (`"xmmN"`). `_mm_movelh_ps()` transfers from the lower 64-bit of a vector register to the upper 64-bit of a vector register.

ARM32 NEON has 64-bit vector registers (`"dN"`). Two consecutive vector registers, the first of which has an even number, can be combined into a 128-bit vector register (`"qN"`).

To get the functionality of `_mm_movelh_ps` in ARM32 NEON, you can use an ordinary 64-bit vector move.

```
#include <immintrin.h>
__m128 foo(__m128 a, __m128 b)
{
  return _mm_movelh_ps(a, b);
}
```

Is equivalent to the following gcc vector intrinsics

```
typedef float v4sf __attribute__((vector_size(16)));
typedef unsigned v4ui __attribute__((vector_size(16)));
v4sf bar(v4sf a, v4sf b)
{
  return __builtin_shuffle(a, b, (v4ui){0, 1, 4, 5});
}
```

Both compile to the same code on my gcc 4.8.4:

```
movlhps %xmm1, %xmm0
ret
```

Unfortunately, gcc 4.9.2 for ARM32 NEON produces *ridiculously* bad code for this:

```
    vldr    d16, .L2
    vldr    d17, .L2+8
    vtbl.8  d18, {d0, d1, d2, d3}, d16
    vtbl.8  d19, {d0, d1, d2, d3}, d17
    vmov    q0, q9  @ v16qi
    bx      lr
```

So you'll probably need to use NEON-intrinsics:

```
#include <arm_neon.h>

float32x4_t foo(float32x4_t a, float32x4_t b)
{
  return vcombine_f32(vget_low_f32(a), vget_low_f32(b));
}
```

which compiles to the expected simple move instruction:

```
    vmov    d1, d2  @ v2sf
    bx      lr
```

Comment: You beat me to it. I was booting up my Raspberry Pi to verify before posting! :)

Comment: @Vallentin: That's why mine is always running ;-)

Comment: That's a very old compiler you've got there.  Is there no way you can upgrade?  What host do you build on?  Maybe I can find you a link.  I can't pass up an opportunity to post links to better compilers.

Comment: @sh1: Well, the x86-64 gcc 4.8.4 is the default of the ancient Mint version I desperately need to ditch. The ARM gcc 4.9.2 is Raspian's default, and the most recent one available there AFAIK. On `gcc.godbolt.org`, gcc 5.4 produces the same code, and 5.4.1 fails even more horribly (it seems it doesn't have proper NEON headers?).

Comment: I googled that and it looks like GCC 6.1 in Stretch is imminent, so maybe just sit and wait for a bit.  But yes, I've also had a lot of trouble with GCC's vector support outside of NEON intrinsics and I'm not completely surprised that the problem is on-going.  You could also try your luck with [Clang nightlies](http://apt.llvm.org/).

Comment: @sh1: In my experience it's not just NEON that gcc struggles with. Generally, gcc's ARM codegen is *much* worse than x86. Or, put another way, x86 codegen gets a lot of eyes and AFAIK also support from Intel. OTOH, clang has gratuitously different and incompatible syntax for `__builtin_shuffle()`, which infuriates me.